# Can the same fusion law for foldr be applied to foldlmap?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, mapreduce, fold

I've read there is no fusion law for `foldl` alone. If I guess correctly, this is due to `foldl` awkwardness for implementing map - which is mostly due to `(foldl cons nil xs)` reversing the list.

If instead we use `conc` lists, then the function `foldlmap` is much nicer in this aspect:

```
(foldlmap list conc nil xs) -> xs
```

If my guess is correct, then there should be a simple fusion law for `foldlmap`. Is this correct?

Comment: What kind of fusion laws are you thinking about - what's the equivalent `foldr` law? Can you give Haskell definitions of `conc` lists and `foldlmap` so the details are clear?

Comment: [The natural fusion law for `foldr` alone that comes to mind is `h (foldr f e xs) = foldr f' e' xs` on suitable conditions on the various functions, but that's hard for a compiler to apply automatically so you might also be thinking of things like `foldr-build` or similar]

Comment: I'm talking about fusion rewrite laws that allow, for example, the compiler to convert `(map f (map g xs)) -> (map (f . g) xs)`. (Edit: yes, what you said.) `conc` is just the usual concatenation. `foldlmap f g z xs = foldl g z (map f xs)`

Comment: i.e. you want something like `foldr-build`?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam yes.

Comment: If you want to stick with the normal `[]` as the underlying datatype I suspect it'll be fiddly, because you lose information about the structure of the concatenation. For example `conc (conc (list 1) (list 2)) (list 3)` is the same list as to `conc (list 1) (conc (list 2) (list 3))`.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I don't understand what you mean... those structures have the same semantical meaning (a flat list) so it makes sense there is no additional structural information carried. [Refer here](http://dustin.sallings.org/2010/03/04/erlang-conc.html) for the original idea (the video mainly).

Comment: They're only semantically equivalent if the user supplied functions obey certain properties.

Answer (score 5):

We can start with the "natural" fold-build fusion rule for an explicit concatenation list type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data ConcList a = List a | Conc (ConcList a) (ConcList a) | Nil

buildCL :: (forall l . (a -> l) -> (l -> l -> l) -> l -> l) -> ConcList a
buildCL g = g List Conc Nil

foldCL :: (a -> v) -> (v -> v -> v) -> v -> ConcList a -> v
foldCL list conc nil cl = go cl
   where
      go (List a) = list a
      go (Conc cl1 cl2) = conc (go cl1) (go cl2)
      go Nil = nil

{-# RULES "foldCL/buildCL"
      forall list conc nil
             (g :: (forall l . (a -> l) -> (l -> l -> l) -> l -> l))
         . foldCL list conc nil (buildCL g) = g list conc nil #-}
```

Then in theory this translates to an equivalent over "normal" lists:

```
buildCL2 :: (forall l . (a -> l) -> (l -> l -> l) -> l -> l) -> [a]
buildCL2 g = g (\a -> [a]) (++) []

{-# RULES "foldl/map/buildCL2"
      forall list conc nil
             (g :: (forall l . (a -> l) -> (l -> l -> l) -> l -> l))
         . foldl conc nil (map list (buildCL2 g)) = g list conc nil #-}
```

But the beauty of `foldr/build` on lists is that it applies to quite a lot of things because a lot of functions are "natural producers" (can be rewritten in terms of `build`) and a lot are natural consumers (can be rewritten in terms of `foldr`). I think the pattern `foldl/map/buildCL2` would be a lot harder to engineer.